# mysql function to divided a sum value of a coulmn and

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a Table call  payments,

```
paymentid   stuid  stu_name   fullamount   pay_comp
1           1234   Jhon       2600         Feb
2           1212   Silva      1300         Jan
3           1234   Jhon       1300         March
4           1212   Silva      3900         April
5           3333   Perera     15600        Dec
```

Here a student can pay for the whole year,for several month or for a single month,Payments are done by 1300,
For a example if "Silva" paid 1300 for the first time he will be paying for Jan.
If he doing a another 1300 payment,Then it will be marked as for next month,Which is "Feb".If someone complete 15600 payment it will be saved as "Dec".
The problem is that when calculating Total Amount for the Jan it must consider that 1300 from Dec payment.

What i want is to calculate total Amount for each month.The problem is "Pay_Com" column is insert records as above.It can be for the whole year or for a single month.Is there any way around this.

I tried different methods,can i use sum of full amount divided by 1300 to calculate full amount for each month.Can anyone suggest me a soultion or a sql Function.
even tried IF and Sum with cases..

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN round(sum(full_amount)/1300) = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Jan',
     CASE
        WHEN round(sum(full_amount)/1300) = 2 THEN 2
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'Feb',
     CASE
        WHEN round(sum(full_amount)/1300) = 3 THEN 3
        ELSE 0
    END AS 'March',
```

Can anyone suggest me a Solution.
Thanks In Advance.

I am Looking for a Something Like.

```
Month   Full_PaymentsRecived
Jan     20000
Feb     3900
....    ....
Dec     2600
```

Comment: Can you pls provide how the expected result would ideally look like based on the sample data? Do you want on overall sum per month or a sum per student per month? What happens if a student starts later than January?

Comment: Thank You For the Reply,
overall sum per month is what i need,

Jan-> {Some Amount}
Feb->{Some Amount}
....
Dec->{Some Amount}

student starts later than Jan is not a requirement.Anyway,I also Have a Student table which has a Join_Date Column.Thanks.

Comment: How are the dates stored in the pay_comp field? Surely not just the abbreviated month name is stored there.

Comment: it is inserted using a Switch.Where i calculate total paidamount for the stuid and divided by 1300 -which defines last pay_month

Comment: In that case I would divide up the payment there for the entire year. It would be a lot simpler.

Comment: Can you please explain it..

Comment: @Shadow,
<code>
SELECT  ROUND(sum(full_amount)/1300) AS completeMonth,stuid FROM payments group by stuid 
</code>
-
Returns the Full payments Done completed  by Students ,Like this.

completeMonth | stuid
:12 |1001: | 
:12 | 1324: |
:10 |1002: | 
:9 | 1333: |


What i want is calculation of full amount for the Month,
15600/1300*12 - Means Jan
15600/1300*11 - Means Feb
.....
15600/1300 - Means Dec

Please help.Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that every stuid is due 1300 every month, you can calculate how much has been paid by every stuid. From this you can apportion forwards from month one decrementing the paid amount as you go.

```
SELECT Y.MM,
            SUM(Y.DUEAMT) PAYMENTSEXPECTED,
            SUM(Y.PAID) PAYMENTSRECEIVED, 
            (SUM(Y.PAID) / SUM(Y.DUEAMT)) * 100 RATIO_PAID_DUE,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Y.PAID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS_RECEIVED,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Y.PAID = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS_MISSED,
            SUM(CASE WHEN Y.PAID < Y.DUEAMT AND Y.PAID > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NUMBER_OF_UNDERPAYMENTS
FROM
(
SELECT X.STUID,X.MM,
         X.DUEAMT,
         #IF(X.STUID <> @P, @TOTALPAID:=(SELECT SUM(FULLAMOUNT) FROM T WHERE T.STUID = X.STUID),0) TOTALPAID,
         IF(X.STUID <> @P, @FULLAMOUNT:=(SELECT SUM(FULLAMOUNT) FROM T WHERE T.STUID = X.STUID) 
         #- X.DUEAMT
         ,
         @FULLAMOUNT:=@FULLAMOUNT - X.DUEAMT) EXHAUST,
         CASE WHEN @FULLAMOUNT >= X.DUEAMT THEN X.DUEAMT
               WHEN @FULLAMOUNT < 0 THEN 0
         ELSE @FULLAMOUNT 
         END AS PAID,

         @P:=X.STUID 
 FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT T.STUID , 1300 AS DUEAMT, S.MM 
FROM T,
(
SELECT 1 AS MM UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION
SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12
) S
) X , (SELECT @TOTALPAID:=0,@FULLAMOUNT:=0,@P:=0) FA
ORDER BY X.STUID,X.MM
) Y
GROUP BY Y.MM
```

The sub query S generates a due amount for each month for each student
The Sub query X then works out and amount paid for each month for each student
The sub query Y then aggregates to get a result (I have added some addition analysis not required in your question).

So given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+----------+
| paymentid | stuid | stu_name | fullamount | pay_comp |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+----------+
|         1 |  1234 | Jhon     |       2600 | Feb      |
|         2 |  1212 | Silva    |       1000 | Jan      |
|         3 |  1234 | Jhon     |       1300 | Mar      |
|         4 |  1212 | Silva    |       3900 | Apr      |
|         5 |  3333 | Perera   |      15600 | Dec      |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+----------+
```

5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

Result

```
MM | PAYMENTSEXPECTED | PAYMENTSRECEIVED | RATIO_PAID_DUE    | NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS_RECEIVED | NUMBER_OF_PAYMENTS_MISSED | NUMBER_OF_UNDERPAYMENTS |
+----+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 |             3900 |             3900 |               100 |                           3 |                         0 |                       0 |
|  2 |             3900 |             3900 |               100 |                           3 |                         0 |                       0 |
|  3 |             3900 |             3900 |               100 |                           3 |                         0 |                       0 |
|  4 |             3900 |             2300 | 58.97435897435898 |                           2 |                         1 |                       1 |
|  5 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
|  6 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
|  7 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
|  8 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
|  9 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
| 10 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
| 11 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
| 12 |             3900 |             1300 | 33.33333333333333 |                           1 |                         2 |                       0 |
+----+------------------+------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+-------------------------+
12 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try that out,

Comment: This is impressive.
Can you please help me with this additional reqquest.
Students Are saved in a separate table called Student,and Paymentexpected is is calculated using 1300 x count(students.stuid)
How can i add this to your query (For PAYMENTSEXPECTED).

Thank You Very Much.